# I can't access my wallet

Tags: blockchain, wallet

i put in my identifier to log in and it stays stuck on the log in page.
It says "changing wallet identifier" and doesn't let me log in.  After a while, it says that they disabled login for too many attempts.
I have not been able to log on for the past 2-3 days.
please help.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE!  Your question is very vague.  It sounds like you're using an online wallet site, but you don't say which one.  Please edit and rewrite your question so it's comprehensible to someone who isn't looking over your shoulder; otherwise it will probably be closed.

Comment: If you're talking about Blockchain then I've been getting the same problem. Still stuck on the log in page.

Comment: Did you understand what's going on? It's doing the same to me now.

Comment: This question needs more information, such as what service this is talking about.

Answer (score 1):

That would be best left to contacting the support of the online wallet.  Most online wallets use that kind of login and usually have a link for support.